# PDFBox- is the reading order guaranteed with PDFTextStripper's processTextPosition ?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, text-extraction

I am using PdfTextStripper (PDFBox 1.8.2) to process every TextPosition in a pdf file. I have tested with a lot of files and I noticed that it processes text in the reading order. However, this does not hold good if a pdf has footers (the docx which I exported as pdf). The pdfTextStripper processes the footer first and then the body of the file.

Is this expected behavior ? Is there a way I can specify the order ? or is there any way I can identify its a footer and I can make the adjustment in my code ?

Answer (score 4):

`PdfTextStripper` has an attribute **SortByPosition** (`getSortByPosition` & `setSortByPosition`). It's `false` by default.

If this attribute is `false,` the `PdfTextStripper` essentially extracts the text in the order in which it appears in the PDF page content stream.

This order can be totally mangled (because in the content stream you use operators which can position the next printed text anywhere on the page) but often text sections belonging together are kept together (because the operations required for such sections often are inserted in that stream as a block).

Headers and footers, though, often are added at the same time and, therefore, appear together before or after the main body text.

If this attribute is `true,` though, the `PdfTextStripper` essentially extracts the text from top to bottom, from left to right (unless the reading order is defined to be right to left). (Ok, ok, it also respects article beads, but you hardly can count on them being used in general.)

This order is good in case of one-column text, and headers come first and footers last, but unless proper article beads are used, multi-column pages get mangled up.

BTW, you can switch off the use of article beads using the attribute `ShouldSeparateByBeads` (`getSeparateByBeads` & `setShouldSeparateByBeads`).